# Transforming string containing a date before 1600 to datetime object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, julian-date

I am working in a dataset of medieval parchments. Trying to convert a date in this format  '1140 01 12' '%Y %m %d' in a pandas DateTime object. Unfortunatly, pandas handles only the dates up to about 1660 with ns resolution. I am okay with a day resolution but I can not make it work:

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'date': ['1140 01 12', '1140 02 16','1140 04 12','1200 10 27'], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6]}
pd.to_datetime(d['date'], format='%Y %m %d',origin = "julian", unit = "D")
```

I have got `ValueError: incompatible 'arg' type for given 'origin'='julian'` any idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pd.Period`:

```
def conv(x):
    year, day, month = map(int, x.split(" "))
    return pd.Period(year=year, month=month, day=day, freq="D")


d = {"date": ["1140 01 12", "1140 02 16", "1140 04 12"], "col2": [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["date"] = df["date"].apply(conv)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         date  col2
0  1140-12-01     3
1  1147-03-18     4
2  1140-12-04     5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why 1200 10 27 is converted Period('57890464-09-29', 'D'), furthermore I am not able to plot the data. Am I doing something wrong?